# Converting Array iteration to lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have below code which iterates over `Cookies` to reset the cookie whose name matches `CookieSession.NAME`

```
  Cookie[] cookies = httpServletRequest.getCookies();
        LOGGER.info("Clearing cookies on welcome page");
        if (cookies != null)
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals(CookieSession.NAME)) {                      
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
              }
            }
```

can someone simplify it using java 8 lambda expression

Comment: yes. but you can start by fixing the lack of `{}` in your if condition

Comment: Not really, no.  It won't be simplified; it'll be basically the same but a little _more_ complicated.

Comment: Lambdas aren't going to make this any simpler. Slower, more memory-heavy, but not simpler.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if it will be simplified, but it can be done, yes:

```
Arrays.stream(cookies)
      .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(CookieSession.NAME))
      .forEach(cookie -> {
          cookie.setValue(null);
          cookie.setMaxAge(0);
          cookie.setPath("/");
          httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
      });
```

Comment: Technically it won't be equivalent as OP's code is missing brackets and only the first setter will depend on the if... but anyway your code does what he expect.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the null check still needs to be done.  `httpServletRequest.getCookies()` returns `null` if there are no cookies and `Arrays.stream` is not null-tolerant.  Also, since `HttpServletResponse` is not specified as thread-safe, `.forEeach` better be replaced with `forEachOrdered`

Answer (score 6):

```
Arrays.stream(httpsServletRequest.getCookies())
    .filter(cookie -> CookieSession.NAME.equals(cookie.getName()))
    .forEach(cookie -> {
        cookie.setValue(null); 
        cookie.setMaxAge(0); 
        cookie.setPath("/");
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie); 
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The `for` loop could be replaced with a `forEach` expression:

```
Arrays.stream(cookies)
      .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(CookieSession.NAME))
      .forEach(c -> {c.setValue(null);
                     c.setMaxAge(0);
                     c.setPath("/");
                     httpServletResponse.addCookie(c);
                    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Other answers seem to have ignored the `if (cookies != null)`. Also I like `peek` for several intermediate operations rather than a block. Seems clearer to me.

```
Optional.ofNullable(httpServletRequest.getCookies())
    .ifPresent(cookies -> Arrays.stream(cookies)
        .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals(CookieSession.NAME))
        .peek(cookie -> cookie.setValue(null))
        .peek(cookie -> cookie.setMaxAge(0))
        .peek(cookie -> cookie.setPath("/"))
        .forEach(httpServletResponse::addCookie));
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to simplify this using a lambda or `forEach`.

Also, many people think that you should not use `forEach` to mutate state in a line like this:

```
cookies.forEach(cookie -> httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie));
```

However, this is really a matter of style. As long as `forEach` consumes the elements sequentially (rather than in parallel), there is nothing that can actually go wrong as a result of a line like that.

[Here is Oracle's advice on the subject](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/moocjdk8/documents/week3/lesson-3-3.pdf).

In my opinion, you should leave your code as it is.

Comment: I'm concerned that your statement regarding Oracle's advice may mislead some readers. There is nothing unsafe about modifying state in a `forEach`. The link you provide argues against the use of `forEach` for stylistic reasons - as providing evidence of not thinking of a better functional solution using mapping and reduction.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll delete my original comment to avoid confusion. I actually agree with your point about whether the new version is any better. But it seems the world is going functional so we'd better get used to it :-)